# Can I turn kernel params to make the network stack using swap instead of physical memory?

Tags: networking, concurrency, kernel-parameters

I'm doing a test about high-currency, and I only have a machine with limited memory.  My goal is to setup more than 10M TCP
connections on this memory limited machine. It seems that the network stack  will only use the physical memory to store the data structures, while there is a lot of swap space, the network stack reported that `no space left on device`

In my test, my goal is simply to reach 10M connections, and not care about the speed or latency, so I want to know is it possible to use a slower storage (i.e., the swap) for the network stack to store the data structures it needs.

Comment: Um ... disk swapping will be much too slow to free up RAM for incoming packets, or to access the necessary tables in time to make the decision for the current packet. This will never work, you can't stop in the middle of the kernel network stack to wait for page swapping. How about using a user space network stack where you can tune memory consumption by simplifying things enough the 10M TCP connections fit into the available memory?

Comment: btw, for your test, here's a Linux reference (to figure out memory etc.) : [Scaling to 12 Million Concurrent Connections: How MigratoryData Did It](https://mrotaru.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/scaling-to-12-million-concurrent-connections-how-migratorydata-did-it/) . appears it needed 36GB of memory for 12M open sockets.

Comment: In a VM this might work (host would be swapping for the VM guest), but you might have your test need months to complete because of trashing, get timeout errors that shouldn't happen etc. [RHEL KVM 7.2. Overcommitting Memory](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-overcommitting_with_kvm-overcommitting_memory)